# What is the use of v-leave CSS class in Vue transition?

Tags: vue.js, css-transitions

Just exploring the possibility of introducing Vue transition to my project, based on the documentation, there are six classes that can be used during the transition process, `v-leave` is one of them, but it doesn't seem to be used in any examples.

So, I created one simple example like below to see how it works, it seems like the class `v-leave` is added to the element but it doesn't have any effect?

Can anyone point out where I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    show: false 
  }
})
```

```css
.v-leave {
  transform: translateY(50px);
} 
.v-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
.v-leave-active{
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.v-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.v-enter-to {
  opacity: 1;
}  
.v-enter-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition>
    <p v-show="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following in order to work in enter/leave:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
   <button v-on:click="show = !show">
    Toggle
  </button>
  <transition name="fade">
    <p v-if="show">hello</p>
  </transition>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity .5s
}
.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0
}
```

Your main problem is to set a name for the transition (in this case `fade`), and then refer it from CSS.

There is a excelent exemple like yours in the [official documentation
Working example [here][1]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

**Edit:**

In the documentation:

> v-leave: Starting state for leave. Added immediately when a leaving
> transition is triggered, removed after **one frame**.

and:

> v-leave-active: Active state for leave. [...] This class can be used to define the duration, delay and easing curve for the leaving transition

The v-leave is only for `detect` the start of the transition (and do something with it), but if you use it, the desired effect will **only** render 1 frame. If you want to use the `leave` animation you should use the `leave-active` to specify the duration and other things.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Have you run my code? It works. If you give your transition a name for example `fade`, then you need to prefix the css like you did there `.fade-enter-active`. 

I didn't use a name here, so the default css class is `v-enter-active`.

Comment: Yes, I did.. and I'm trying to explain why in the leave part isn't working. In your example, when enter the transition works well (fade in), but when leave, no. If you do like in the *official* Vue.js tutorial (and mine) *it works in the both actions*. If I'm missing something to help you, let me know. If you want to know `why` isn't working your example, is a different issue.

Comment: I mean, in your example, there is no `.fade-leave` class right? And if you read through the documentation, there actually is a `.v-leave` class that can be used in leave transition, in your case it should be updated as `.fade-leave` correspondingly. 

My issue is, I add the `.v-leave` class and it's not working, in your example, there is no `.fade-leave` class at all ( even in official documentation, author didn't use `.v-leave` either). 

Is that clear?

Comment: See my edit, maybe it clarifies your question, you said: `I add the .v-leave class and it's not working`, maybe "it's working" but only 1 frame (you can't see it).

Comment: That's odd, since if can see from my code that it is an obvious move (moving down 50px)

Thanks for the explanation anyway :)

Comment: If you solved your problem, mark the question as resolved in order to keep S.O clean, and If the answer helps you, upvote ;).